# Optional parameter to function type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Say I have the following (trivial) flow.js example:

```
type Example = (d: number, b?: string) => void

const f:Example = (d: number, boo: string) => {}
```

This fails to compile with:

```
const f:Example = (d: number, boo: string) => {}
                                      ^ Cannot assign function to `f` because string [1] is incompatible with undefined [2] in the second argument.
References:
3: const f:Example = (d: number, boo: string) => {}
                                      ^ [1]
1: type Example = (d: number, b?: string) => void
                                  ^ [2]
```

I'm trying to understand why? I thought the second parameter (b) was annotated as optional, e.g. if it does not exist that's fine, but if it exists it has to be a string?

Clearly this is not accurate. What's the actual explanation of what's going on here? And how can I have the behavior I'm after (e.g., a function which takes either one or two arguments, and when the second argument exists it must be a string)

Try flow link: https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDbQLxQBQBMBcUAdgK5IBGEATgDRTkD8hAzsFQJZEDmAlFBgD4oANwD27XAChJAY1FFWUAGb54yNJhwFiZSrXqjRLNp178hAbwC+QA

Comment: As a side-note, keep in mind that optional parameters are typically used when writing function definitions, not when declaring function types for callback-style APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An optional parameter `?` means the caller may or may not provide the argument. It does *not* mean that a particular callee can choose whether or not to ignore the parameter.

The error is telling you that the function `f` always expects a string argument even though it is not always provided, according to the `Example` type.

What you *probably* meant to do was:

```
type Example = (d: number, b: string) => void

const f: Example = (d: number, boo: string) => {}
const g: Example = (d: number) => {}
```

#### [Try it out](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDbQLxQBQBMBcUAdgK5IBGEATgDRTmEDOwVAlkQOYCUUGAfFABuAe1a4AUOIDGwosygAzQvGRpMOAsTKVa9YcKYt23XgIDeAX2mz5HZYhTpeGwqQrUe-KJaA)

This is valid because the string argument is always provided, but the callee can choose whether or not to use the argument.